# Get current position in the line / get space until end of line

Tags: positioning, algorithmicx

How can I get the current position within the line? Or how can I find out how much space is left until the end of line? (With the help of `\linewidth` it is easy to deduct one value from the other)

Here is an example of what I want to achieve (the example is done with manual spacing).

[image: example]

I want to know the width of the red box (red box is inserted my me in the screenshot). After I know the length it is easy to do something like this:

```
\addtolength{\MYLENGTH}{-2em} 
\hspace{2em}\parbox[t]{\MYLENGTH}{#1}
```

Background:
I am using the algpseudocode package to write pseudocode. The package provides a `\Comment` command to place comments after the lines. I want to have longer comments that span over multiple lines as shown in the screenshot.

**What have I tried so far?**

- Usind the `linegoal` package. This worked *somehow*, but the value that the package determines changes (slightly) every time I compile it. It also has a strange error that the value is always wrong by a constant difference.
- Following the answers here: [How to get element position in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37297/how-to-get-element-position-in-latex). This worked so far that I get the absolute position, but I am unable to determine the relative position from that. If I could know the absolute x-position of the end of line I could determine the spacing, but how to do that?
- Measuring everything that is positioned left of the red box manually. This works but I need to know before what will be positioned there. Using that method is cumbersome.

Comment: Using the `tabto` package, the value of `\TabPrevPos` contains the value of the horizontal location on the line just prior to the most recent tabbing.  This can be used in the manner needed by the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The document I needed it for, is long finished. I am not even sure where the source code is. So I can not really test your suggestion. But maybe it is useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `linegoal` changes its results is twofold: One is that it requires two compilations, after which it should stabilize; the second for the slight changes *might be* because it isn't returning a position but rather one relative to the remaining `\linewidth`, which may be changing for reasons of kerning decisions or something.

For absolute position you can use the `zref` subpackage `zref-savepos` (which `linegoal` uses) (And in either case you can only use pdfTex or XeTex -- no LuaTeX or DVI outputs). Then you use the following command combo:

```
\zsaveposx{<yourlabel>) % tells pdfTeX to save the current position (x-coord) once generated; returns nothing; can be used inline; expands variables in argument
\zposx{<yourlabel>) % returns the saved x-coord once generated, or 0? if not yet generated (not cycled thru compilation yet); also usable inline
```

The resulting coordinates are in sp *I think*, but at least [an answer on column detection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247449/making-marginnote-to-appear-either-side-of-twocolumn-twoside-document-part-ii) gives us a page midpoint (19000000) and what to test ("stop" and "start2") for comparing where you are. I used the following functions for my recent twocolumn tweaks:

```
\def\islcol#1{\ifnum 0#1<19000000 1\else 0\fi\relax}
\newcommand\isleftcol[1][blahlabel]{\zsaveposx{pos-#1} \islcol{\zposx{#1}}}
```

Comment: Can you please add an short compilable tex code showing your solution?