# How can I create a box which extends to the end of the line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, dimensions, parbox

I want to create a (par)box which starts wherever I am right now and extends to the end of the line. I noticed this related question:

[Get current position in the line / get space until end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245076/get-current-position-in-the-line-get-space-until-end-of-line)

and, indeed, if I could get the position I could do position arithmetic; but perhaps there's another, simpler way to do it?

Comment: Related Question (within `align`): [Compute remaining horizontal space in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100495/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following uses [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module to store the x-coordinate at the call to `\fillparbox`, as well as the x-coordinate after issuing an `\hfill`. The difference between these two x-coordinates then provides the width of a `\parbox` that you can place there:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcounter{fillparbox}
\newcommand{\fillparbox}[2][c]{%
  \stepcounter{fillparbox}% New \fillparbox
  \mbox{}\zsaveposx{\thefillparbox-L}\hfill\zsaveposx{\thefillparbox-R}% Mark Left and Right end-points remaining on line.
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\parbox[#1]{\dimexpr\zposx{\thefillparbox-R}sp-\zposx{\thefillparbox-L}sp}{\strut #2\strut}}%
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\fillparbox{\itshape\bfseries one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
eleven twelve thirteen}

\lipsum[2]
\fillparbox{\itshape\bfseries one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
eleven twelve thirteen}

\lipsum[3]
\fillparbox[t]{\itshape\bfseries one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
eleven twelve thirteen}

\end{document}
```

You can still issue the various alignment options association with `\parbox`, the default being `[c]`entred (vertically). `\strut`s are inserted to ensure a consistent baseline (see [How to keep a constant `\baselineskip` when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764)).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can use the pdftex `\pdfsavepos` extension to record the point on the line.
This will also work in xetex, and with some name changes (or with `luatex85` package) in luatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcount\zzcount
\def\zz#1{\global\advance\zzcount\@ne
\edef\tmp{\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\ZZ\romannumeral\zzcount{\noexpand\the\pdflastxpos}}}%
\tmp
\expandafter\ifx\csname  ZZ\romannumeral\zzcount\endcsname\relax
\message{first pass re-run latex to see zz box}%
\dotfill
\else
\dimen@\dimexpr\csname  ZZZ\romannumeral\zzcount\endcsname sp-\csname  \romannumeral\zzcount\endcsname sp\relax
\ifdim\dimen@>\p@
\parbox[t]%
{\dimen@}%
{\itshape\bfseries#1}\hfill
\else
\message{something wrong try deleting aux file}%
XX\dotfill
\fi
\fi
\edef\tmp{\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\ZZZ\romannumeral\zzcount{\noexpand\the\pdflastxpos}}}
\tmp
}
\begin{document}

aaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaa
aaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaa
aaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaa

aaa aaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa
\zz{one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
eleven twelve thirteen}

aaa aaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa
bbb bb bbb bb bbb bbbb
\zz{one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
eleven twelve thirteen}


\end{document}
```