# \linewidth in expex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics, tabu, expex, zref

It seems to me that examples in `expex` have no effect on the length of `\linewidth`, which is especially annoying if you want to put two things next to each other with a minipage, or you include a table.

I have already [found out about the existence of `zref-abspos`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37297/how-to-get-element-position-in-latex), however, the values I get from this are also strange, and `tabu` doesn't seem to heed them anyway for some reason. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{zref-abspos}
\newlength{\remaining}
\newcommand{\remain}[1]{%
    \zsavepos{#1}%
    \setlength{\remaining}{\linewidth minus \zposx{#1}sp}%
}
\begin{document}
The linewidth: \the\linewidth. \lipsum[1]
\pex
\a \remain{test}%
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {| X | X |}
\hline
    Linewidth & \the\linewidth \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\a \begin{tabu} to \remaining {| X | X |}
\hline
    Remaining & \the\remaining \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\xe

\begin{itemize}
    \item Linewidth: \the\linewidth
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Linewidth: \the\linewidth
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get when I try to calculate the distance between the example text and the left page margin. `expex` doesn't seem to provide this distance as a length, at least the documentation doesn't mention it explicitly, only `numoffset` (distance between page margin and example number) and `textoffset` (distance between example number and text). 174pt seems way too much, however, since the text even for the second-level bullet point is just 47.0003pt in.

[image: Example of trying to use zref-abspos to get the distance between the example text and the left page margin]

It also does not seem to be possible to access the indentation length for examples with `enumitem`'s `textoffset`.

Comment: It's not clear what you try to do here but `minus`  does not subtract the two lengths, which I think might be the intention.

Comment: I seem to have gotten confused there by LaTeX returning `\the\length`s in this format

Comment: the syntax is legal but it isn't subtraction a length of `5pt plus 2pt minus 1pt` is a stretchy length with natural size 5pt which can shrink to 4pt and stretch to 7pt.  to do 5pt - 1pt use `\dimexpr 5pt - 1pt \relax.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to be able to add tables which take up the space remaining in the ExPex example line. ExPex doesn't use LaTeX `list` constructs to build the enumerations, so as you observe, `\linewidth` is not a parameter that is updated by ExPex.  So you are right that you need to calculate the remaining space. To do this you need to use the lengths that ExPex uses in its construction of the example numbers.

Two calculations are needed, depending on whether the example is an `\ex` example or a `\pex` example.  To make things simple, I've used `etoolbox` to prepend the calculation automatically, so that the `\remaining` value is calculated for every example.  I've used the `showframe` option of `geometry` to show that the calculation is correct. For testing purposes I've repeated both types of examples using `pgffor` to show different example numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newlength{\remaining}

\newcommand{\remainpex}{%
   \setlength{\remaining}{\linewidth-\lingtextoffset-\linglabelwidth-
      \lingnumoffset-\linglabeloffset-\widthof{\exnoprint}}%
}
\newcommand{\remainex}{%
   \setlength{\remaining}{\linewidth-\lingnumoffset-
      \lingtextoffset-\widthof{\exnoprint}}%
}
\pretocmd{\pex}{\remainpex}{}{}
\pretocmd{\ex}{\remainex}{}{}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,10,100}{
\excnt=\x
\pex
\a %
%
\begin{tabu} to \remaining {| X | X |}
\hline
    sometext & sometext \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\a \begin{tabu} to \remaining {| X | X |}
\hline
    sometext & sometext \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\xe
\ex
\begin{tabu} to \remaining {| X | X |}
\hline
    sometext & sometext \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\xe
}
\end{document}
```

[image: ouptut of code]